# Error running Karate ui test in containers

Tags: karate

I am having an issue running karate UI tests in the containers.
I am able to clearly run the tests in the local .But my test runs in container says "ERROR com.intuit.karate - driver config / start failed:"
I am using driver config as below

- configure driver = { type: 'chrome', headless: true, showDriverLog: true, addOptions: ['--incognito'], httpConfig: { readTimeout: 120000 }}
  I am not using any other configs.
  Has anyone been in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers are not easy and you seem to be trying some approach of your own (also headless). Please follow the Karate documentation and use the recommended Docker containers.

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-chrome

If still stuck kindly follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and help up improve / fix the framework (and provide more details).